# Temporal segmentation algorithms using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, change-detection

I'm using the temporal segmentation algorithm Vegetation Regeneration and Disturbance Estimates - Verdet - for land cover change detection. The output layer is created but I can't display or export it (GEE returns processing errors). Does anyone know how can I work with this tool?

```js
// NDVI image collection from Landsat TM
var collection5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 219))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 72))
    .filterDate('2008-01-01', '2011-12-31')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'equals', 0);

  var segIndex = function(img){
      var index = img.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5']);
      return index;
  };
  var collection5 = collection5.map(segIndex);

// NDVI image collection from Landsat OLI
var collection8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 219))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 72))
    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2017-12-31')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'equals', 0);

  var collection8 = collection8.map(segIndex);

// Merge collections
var merge = ee.ImageCollection(collection5.merge(collection8));

// Run VerDET
var verdet = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Verdet(merge);
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that you're calculating NDVI incorrectly. The NDVI bands for Landsat 8 are B5 and B4; the NDVI bands for Landsat 5 are B4 and B3. In Earth Engine, the `.normalizedDifference` method subtracts the second band from the first band and divides the result by the sum of the two bands. You've provided the arguments as `.normalizedDifference('B4', 'B5')` instead of `.normalizedDifference('B5', 'B4')`. As a result, all of your NDVI scores are negative and the VerDET output is nonsensical. So for Landsat 8, you'd want something like:

```js
// NDVI image collection from Landsat OLI
var collection8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 219))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 72))
    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2017-12-31')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'equals', 0)
    .map(function(image) {
        return image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
    });
```

The other issue is the source of the internal server error. The exact cause of this is not clear, but it's probably due an out-of-memory error. You'll notice that some tiles finish, while other tiles do not. It appears that the edge tiles, with less imagery in them, are completing, which suggests that its a memory error. Furthermore, it seems like the algorithm is able to complete only when running on fewer images. You might try running the code on a collection of annual composites to reduce the number of images that its running on, but the solution is primarily going to have to come from Google; it seems like sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't.

The following code runs the VerDET analysis on Landsat 8 only: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/25b7db815d4f9c40e56b145b340f4de8

Comment: Thank you so much @svangordon ! I solved the NDVI issue (my bad), but the internal server error still remains either to the followed code (I can't zoom in or export) or to annual composites. Verdet returns a _"dimension: 1"_ output layer, which is very curious... but thanks anyway.